# ExcelAnt add-ins in Workbook_Open won't run if the workbook was opened by another workbook's macro

Tags: excel, vba

Currently making a quick macro that opens a bunch of other workbooks in new instances:

```
Sub open_files()
    Dim Path As String
    Dim Fname As String
    Dim xlApp As Object
    MyFiles = Dir("C:\my_folder\*xls*")
    Do While MyFiles <> ""
        Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        xlApp.Visible = True
        xlApp.Workbooks.Open ("C:\my_folder\" & MyFiles)
        MyFiles = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

This works fine on sheets that don't have any ExcelAnt functions in Workbook_Open, but for those that do, I get a popup that says: "Run-time error '1004': cannot run the macro 'Connect'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled. "

I've tried forcing in the add-in before running the "connect" part of the code but to no avail.

```
Public Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim TestWkbk As Workbook
    Set TestWkbk = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    Set TestWkbk = Workbooks("ExcelAnt-AddIn64.xll")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If TestWkbk Is Nothing Then
        Set TestWkbk = Workbooks.Open("C:\ExcelAnt\ExcelAnt-AddIn64.xll")
    End If
    
    Dim hostenv As String
    hostenv = Left(Environ("computername"), 3)
    
    Application.Run "Connect", "prd"
End Sub
```

To clarify, the sheet if opened manually works fine.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `xlApp.RegisterXLL "C:\ExcelAnt\ExcelAnt-AddIn64.xll"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`RegisterXLL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.registerxll) with the new instance of Excel (`xlApp`).

```
xlApp.RegisterXLL "C:\ExcelAnt\ExcelAnt-AddIn64.xll"
```